# How to prevent mod_rewrite from rewriting URLs more than once?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use mod_rewrite to rewrite a few human-friendly URLs to arbitrary files in a folder called `php` (which is inside the web root, since mod_rewrite apparently won't let you rewrite to files outside the web root).

```
/        --> /php/home.php
/about   --> /php/about_page.php
/contact --> /php/contact.php
```

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ php/home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about$ php/about_page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ php/contact.php [L]
```

However, I also want to prevent users from accessing files in this `php` directory directly. If a user enters **any** URL beginning with `/php`, I want them to get a 404 page.

I tried adding this extra rule at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^php php/404.php [L]
```

...(where 404.php is a file that outputs 404 headers and a "Not found" message.)

But when I access `/` or `/about` or /`contact`, I always get redirected to the 404. It seems the final RewriteRule is applied even to the internally rewritten URLs (as they now all start with `/php`).

I thought the `[L]` flag (on the first three RewriteRules) was supposed to prevent further rules from being applied? Am I doing something wrong? (Or is there a smarter way to do what I'm trying to do?)

Answer (score 0):

[L] flag should be used only in the last rule,

L - Last Rule - Stops the rewriting process here and don’t apply any more rewriting rules & because of that you are facing issues.

Comment: But that's exactly what I want, to end the rewriting process here. I am saying I *don't* want it to continue applying subsequent rules after one has matched. But the final rule always gets executed, even when a previous rule (with [L] flag) has already been executed. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I have a content management system written in PHP and based on Model-View-Control paradigm. The most base part is the `mod_rewrite`. I've successfully prevent access to PHP files globally. The trick has name `THE_REQUEST`.

**What's the problem?**

Rewriting modul rewrites the URI. If the URI matches a rule, it is rewritten and other rules are applied on the new, rewritted URI. But! If the matched rule ends with `[L]`, the engine doesn't terminate in fact, but starts again. Then the new URI doesn't more match the rule ending with `[L]`, continues and matches the last one. Result? The programmer stars saying bad words at the unexpected 404 error page. However computer does, what you say and doesn't do, what you want. I had this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^plugins/.* pluginLoader.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

That's wrong. Even the URIs beginning with `plugins/` are rewritten to `index.php`.

**Solution**

You need to apply the rule if and only if the original - not rewritten - URI matches the rule. Regrettably the `mod_rewrite` does not provide any variable containing the original URI, but it provides some `THE_REQUEST` variable, which contains the first line of HTTP request header. This variable is invariant. It doesn't change while rewrite engine is working.

```
...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s.*\.php\s
RewriteRule \.php$ index.php [L]
```

The regular expression is different. It is not applied on the URI only, but on entire first line of the header, that means on something like `GET /script.php HTTP/1.1`. But the critical rule is this time applied  only if the user is explicitly requesting some PHP-script directly. The rewritten URI is not used.